# Xamarin Forms CarouselPage ActivityIndicator in every ContentPages not working

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I have a CarouselPage in which I have around 6 Content Pages
Every Page has a ListView for a selection list.
When the ListItem is selected (tapped) user is taken to next ContentPage with appropriate criteria on based on previous selection.
Its all working smooth.
But at sometimes it is taking time at certain Pages.
I want to display a ActivityIndicator to user so that he do not feel like he did not tapped or he attempts double tapping or any such waiting issues.

What I have worked:-

This is CarouselPage Start Header information

```
<CarouselPage x:Name="CarouselPage_Selection_Page"
              xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"  
              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:saralEHR"
              Padding="0"
              Title="Selection Pages">
```

Following is the XAML Code:-

```
   <ContentPage Padding="5"
        x:Name="ContentPage_Select_Visiting_Location">
        <Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent" RowSpacing="0" Margin="10" Padding="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="108"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Black">
                <Label Text="SELECT LOCATION" BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="White"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <ListView x:Name="ListView_Visiting_Location_Name"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Visiting_Location_Name_Table}" 
                            ItemTapped="ListView_Visiting_Location_Name_ItemTapped">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label x:Name="Label_Visiting_Location_Name"
                                            Text="{Binding Visiting_Location_Name}"
                                            FontAttributes="Bold">
                                    </Label>
                                    <Label x:Name="Label_Visiting_Location_ID"
                                            Text="{Binding Visiting_Location_ID, StringFormat='{0:F0}'}"
                                            IsVisible="False">
                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
                <ActivityIndicator 
                        x:Name="ActivityIndicator_Busy_Selected_Visiting_Location"
                        Color="Black"
                        IsEnabled="True" 
                        HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        IsRunning="{Binding Source={x:Reference ContentPage_Select_Visiting_Location}, Path=IsBusy}" 
                        IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference ContentPage_Select_Visiting_Location}, Path=IsBusy}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage>
```

And Finally this is the xaml.cs code behind file:-

```
protected async void ListView_Visiting_Location_Name_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    string where_clause = "";

    ContentPage_Select_Visiting_Location.IsBusy = true;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                Sql_Common.selected_appointments_booking_Visiting_Location_ID = (e.Item as Visiting_Location_Master).Visiting_Location_ID;
                Sql_Common.selected_appointments_booking_Visiting_Location_name = (e.Item as Visiting_Location_Master).Visiting_Location_Name;

                ActivityIndicator_Busy_Selected_Visiting_Location.IsRunning = true;
                ActivityIndicator_Busy_Selected_Visiting_Location.IsVisible = true;

                await Task.Delay(3000);

                Load_Slot_Date_Details();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error!", ex.Message + where_clause, "Ok");
            }

            int index = Children.IndexOf(CurrentPage);
            this.CurrentPage = this.Children[index + 1];

            ActivityIndicator_Busy_Selected_Visiting_Location.IsRunning = false;

            this.IsBusy = false;

        });

    });

    ActivityIndicator_Busy_Selected_Visiting_Location.IsRunning = false;

    this.IsBusy = false;

    ContentPage_Select_Visiting_Location.IsBusy = false;
}
```

You may find I have done lot of workouts like this.IsBusy = true, ActivityIndicator_Busy_Selected_Visiting_Location.IsRunning = true; etc but nothing is working.

Any help regarding same would be highly appreciable.

**I have google a lot of topics but nothing found specific running ActivityIndicator in individual ContentPage in CarouselPage which has several ContentPage**

Comment: It appears that your `ActivityIndicator` is nested in `StackLayout`. Move it outside of there, so it's a child of the `Grid`

Comment: @Ale_lipa Can you post this as an answer. I would comment in detail on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per OP request, I'm making my comment an answer.

> It appears that your `ActivityIndicator` is nested in the
>   `StackLayout`. Move it outside of there, so it's a child of the `Grid`

Comment: Exactly I did you suggested and worked out immediately. Not only that after implementing in all pages, all pages too gave smooth response to ActivityIndicator. Super Thanks.